# iOS - didRecieveRemoteNotification not working when app is not running

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, apple-push-notifications

Push notifications are calling `didReceiveRemoteNotification` when the app is running or when it's in background. 
But if the user "kills" the app and I send a push notification, when the user taps on the notification, the app doesn't call `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

This is what I have:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)dict{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:dict[@"title"]
                                                message:dict[@"description"]
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];

NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification: %@", dict);}
```

Comment: Sean is correct. Also UIAlertView is depreciated and has been replaced with UIAlertController .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to UIApplicationDelegate protocol reference:

> If the app is not running when a remote notification arrives, the
>   method launches the app and provides the appropriate information in
>   the launch options dictionary. The app does not call this method to
>   handle that remote notification. Instead, your implementation of the
>   application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: or
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method needs to get the
>   remote notification payload data and respond appropriately.

When your app launches the applicationDidFinishLaunching will have data with any remote notifications received while the application was terminated. Use the code below when your application has finished launching.

```
if ([launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) 
{
   [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]];
}
```

Source https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:

Comment: @VidalRmrz make sure to mark the answer as correct so others know it worked.